# The concept of the solution space and its possible combination in the logical (Binary) modeling

Tags: solution-verification, mathematical-modeling, linearization

There is a following logical optimization problem.

$$\text{Max} \text{   } \text{OF} = z$$
$$\text{S.t:} \quad (x+y=1) \implies (z \leq 20)$$
$$x,y \in \text{{0,1}} ,z \in \mathbb{R}^+$$

I know, there are some linearizations to solve such a problem efficiently. But, What I am getting stuck on is if, one equals the term $(x+y)$ to a new auxiliary variable, in this case $w$, how can ensure it consists of all of the feasible solution space? Let's say if, one turns out the above logical constraint into $x+y \geq 1-w$ and then replaces the original logical constraint to $(w=1) \implies (z \leq 20)$, The problem may solve with an optimal solution, but it seems to allow $(x,y,w)=(1,1,1)$ and disallow $(x,y,w)=(0,0,0)$.

As $x$ and $y$ are binary, the solution space and its combination would be, (if I am thinking wrong please, correct me): there exist four combinations and three possible feasible solutions for $x+y$. $\text{ {(0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(1,1)} }$ combinations respectively, and $\text{ {0,1,2} }$ feasible solution space.

Also, I tried $(x+y \geq 1-w)$, $(x+y=w)$, etc. but, in all of the cases, the optimal solution is the same as the solvers like Gurobi, CPLEX, and Pyomo-GDP returned by whose specific logical modeling features!!!

My main question is, how we can actually ensure that the solution we can achieve by linearization ***is really feasible*** when the optimal solution is the same as the reported solution by the solver?

Answer (score 0):

One of the users on the OR site suggested something like this:
$ x+y = 2*v+w$ where $ 0 \le v \le 1$ is binary while $ 0 \le w \le 1$.
Then the usual
$ z \le 20w + z_{max}(1-w)$.
$ v$ can be binary but I always try with relaxation to see if that works.

Comment: This approach requires $v$ to be binary.  Otherwise $(x,y,z,v,w)=(1,0,100,1/2,0)$ is feasible when it should not be.  However, if $x,y,v$ are binary, then you can relax $w$ because it will automatically take values in $\{0,1\}$.

Comment: Agree, corrected the post

Comment: @Sutanu, Thanks for the comments. But, I really like to know, how we can enumerate all possible solutions of such space. I think without knowing this there might be many possible constraints to satisfying the solution space and finding the best one is somewhat impossible. Do you have any experience with such a case?

Comment: That's PhD level stuff, I am just a practitioner with a Masters. Still I believe to enumerate/imagine solution space, one needs to get more & more data. That's what we see in ML as well, more and more observations to enumerate practical combinations of features.  Its complicated. Like even in binary space, is it really binary or is it 0.95 and 0.01? Can 0.95/0.01 give us good enough solution space that will remain feasible no matter what future observations we record? I don't have an answer to that.

Comment: @RobPratt, why not try to use $x+y=w$ and restrict $w$ on the $\{0,1,2\}$? It seems to cover all feasible solutions without disrupting any things.

Comment: @Sutanu, what is your idea?

Comment: If you introduce $w\in\{0,1,2\}$ and impose $x+y=w$, you cannot use $w$ as an indicator variable because it is not binary.

Comment: @RobPratt, many thanks. Then the only way would be something like what proposed by Sutanu. Or something like what proposed by one of gurobi staff.